# By using groovy scripts local property value is not updated in SOAP UI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I have written below groovy script to update the local test case property values in Properties tab:

```
String testString = "TestString"
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "Pro_Response", testString )
def getLocalPropValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Pro_Response")
log.info(getLocalPropValue)
```

So after running this groovy script my expected out put is Pro_Response property should be updated with testString value. But this is not happening.

Note: There is no issues wit the groovy log.info(getLocalPropValue) is giving me the  testString value in script output.

Can anyone plse suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found below solution for this issue:
Since I was looking to modify the property in Properties test step:

I need to modify below existing line of code:

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "Pro_Response", testString )

Like below:

testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties_2"].setPropertyValue( "Pro_Response", testString )